# Updating a SQL db from a php file Concurrently from two different webpages

Tags: php, mysql

so the client requires that I need to know which users are online, my logic is this, every 2 seconds, update the database with a "last ping time" value, if the user's last ping time is greater than 30 seconds, the tab is closed, or the network is disconnected.

I'm running into the issue though, that this works, the mysqli_query returns 1 and the username is valid, I see the database is getting updated. BUT if I open the community page, that attempts to access the same php file and database concurrently, then I get an empty response, in addition, the page refuses to reload for awhile after that.

I get

```
9jquery.min.js:2 POST http://xxx/onlineupdate.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I presume that the server (cpanel via godaddy, php 7.3, mysql database) thinks it's a DDOS attack or something of the kind, is my thinking wrong? Here is what I was going for:

So I put this in the footer, to update the server that the user is still online at 2 seconds intervals.

```
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
   var ajaxurl = 'onlineupdate.php',
        data =  {'here':'here',
                 'username':<?php echo '\''.$_SESSION['username'].'\'';?>
        };
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                });

    },2000);
</script>
```

Here is onlineupdate.php

```
//onlineupdate.php
<?php
     include("connection.php");
     date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
     if(isset($_POST['here'])){
         $usernm = $_POST['username'];
         $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
         $sql_status = "UPDATE users SET active_status='1', modified_date='$date' WHERE username='$usernm'";    
         $result_status = mysqli_query($con,$sql_status);
         echo $usernm;
         echo $result_status;
         exit;
     }
      if(isset($_POST['there'])){
         $usernm = $_POST['username'];
         $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');   
         $ac_sql_time="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usernm'";
         $result=mysqli_query($con,$ac_sql_time);
         $rowData=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         $last = $rowData["modified_date"];

         $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
         $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
         $time = $timestamp - (10);

         $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
         if($last<$datetime)
         {
             echo '1';
         }
         exit;
     }
?>
```

community.php excerpt

```
function hookUser(user)
                {
                    console.log('HOOKED USER: '+user);
                     setInterval(
                         function()
                         {
                            var ajaxurl = 'checkonline.php',
                            data =  {'there':'here'
                                ,'username':user};
                             var button = document.getElementById('button_'+user);
                            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                                if(response=='1'){
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    button.innerHTML = 'ONLINE';
                                    button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-success';
                                }else{
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    button.innerHTML = 'OFFLINE';
                                    button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
                                }
                            });
                         },2000);
                }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I guess you're aware that this code is open to injection, but 'heads up', just in case.

Comment: NOTE: when using a different IP for the community page, then it's fine

Comment: @Strawberry can you give me an example of how please if it's not too much trouble so I can test?